# What is the chromatic number of the n-halved cube graph?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

The n-halved cube graph is the bipartite half of the n-hypercubic graph. I know that the chromatic number of the n-halved cube graph, denoted d(n), is n iff n is a power of two. Also, d(2^n-1) = 2^n, and d(5) = d(6) = 8. What is d(n) in general?

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HalvedCubeGraph.html has a bit more data: it says that $d(9)$ is $13$ or $14$, $d(10)$ is between $13$ and $15$, and $d(11)$ is either $15$ or $16$. I haven't been able to find the original citation. There's also https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/graphs/cubelike.html, with the same information (plus $d(13) = d(14) = 16$).

Comment: The lower bounds come from dividing the number of vertices by the independence number, which is given for $n=1, \dots, 16$ in http://oeis.org/A005864.